# Using ctid to update table

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I translate t-sql code to PostgreSQL. I have temp table, which structure i can't change. This table have only index without PK. In t-sql to update columns in this table i using this:

```
update t
set col_1 = tt.val
from table_1 t 
inner join table_2 tt on t.col_2 = tt.col_2
```

But in Postgres i need join my temp table with themself for update, so can I use `ctid` column for it (instead of PK), or this method have problems? I read that `vacuum` can change `ctid`.

```
update table_1
set col_1 = tt.val
from table_1 t 
inner join table_2 tt on t.col_2 = tt.col_2
where table_1.ctid = t.ctid
```

upd: update question

Comment: This sounds like a continuation of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75661361/using-row-number-in-update), no? Or do you now have a primary key `id` in your table (that is referenced by `t_id` in the second table)?

Comment: "*I read that vacuum can change `ctid`.*" - so what? There's no `VACUUM` in your `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: What does "*This table have only index without PK*" mean? What index, a unique index on `id`?

Comment: @Bergi, update question, in this table no PK and id, only unique index on (col_2, col_3)

Comment: Well you shouldn't need a primary key then, just use those columns for the joining. Or are you saying your temporary table has `NULL` values in them?

Comment: Yes in table can be NULL value in this columns

Answer (score 0):

The `WITH cte` used to get the id and `val` from table_2, then we can update col1 using update join

Your First Query can be translated to something like this :

```
with cte as (
  select t.id, tt.val
  from table_1 t 
  inner join table_2 tt on t.id = tt.t_id
)
update table_1 t
set col_1 = cte.val
from cte
where t.id = cte.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to update values in table_1 based on data in table_2. In Postgres you should not repeat the target table in the FROM clause. So the original T-SQL UPDATE statement translates to the following in Postgres:

```
update table_1
  set col_1 = tt.val
from table_2 tt 
where table_1.col_2 = tt.col_2
```

Comment: Sorry fo my first example, it wrong, I update question

Comment: @e1s: that doesn't really change anything. You are just doing the join on different columns.